# Apply same event to every project button in a C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project with 3 forms and 10 user controls. Each of these components has around 10 buttons. 
I would like to use an event to apply a style when they are hovered by the user. Is there a way that I can create this event for the general component and then it would be applied to each component automatically? 
Because I am not necessarily in the mood to go through 130 buttons event manually ^^

Comment: There are more options how to do that. When I have many controls that have a different function _(especially when used in more than one form)_, I create a new custom control with different behaviour. Then it is simple to replace all the controls _(with 'Replace' function in editor)_ to the new control.

Comment: Create one button event method and just change the buttons properties to use that event receiver

Comment: off topic but if the project is small and you wish to maintain it for a long time then consider switching to WPF which gives you this ability right out of the box and much more.

Comment: you can enumerate the buttons and do the event binding at runtime, so there will be no need to click through the designer/properties window.

Comment: @dlatikay runtime enumeration is slow and doing it with reflection is very inefficient especially when dealing with buttons within other (user-defined) controls from the form class. The best bet in this scenario is what Julo proposed and I expanded upon in my answer.

Comment: there is no reflection involved in enumerating over a control collection. but on the other hand, as OP already has grouped them in ~10 per user control, this seems manageable at design-time too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option probably would be to subclass the button class, and use that throughout the rest of your code. Reflecting through all your forms and user-defined controls to identify and add an event handler to each button will be costly (both in terms of developer time and run time). Since the [Button class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button) isn't sealed, you can easily override the [OnMouseHover()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onmousehover#System_Windows_Forms_Control_OnMouseHover_System_EventArgs_) method to update the button as needed (making sure to call the base class method before leaving your override).

Comment: This is what I will go for, despite Luna's answer was also a good idea, this one fits better to what I am looking for

Answer (score 4):

You could use a recursive method and call it on your form. It will go through all the child controls of your form, and their children, and if they are a button, it will link them to your centralised method.

Here's an example with a Click event, but it could apply to anything:

```
    private void RecursiveClickSubscribe(Control c)
    {
        if (c is Button)
        {
            c.Click += GenericClickHandler;
        }
        foreach (Control child in c.Controls)
        {
            RecursiveClickSubscribe(child);
        }

    }

    private void GenericClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // stuff you want to do on every click
    }

    Form myForm; // one of your three forms.
    RecursiveClickSubscribe(MyForm);
```

Comment: What you could still do is to create a baseform that does this, and inherit all forms from that baseform. Now you dont have to think about calling this code anymore it will be always be done

Comment: Of course if one goes to the "trouble" of deriving their subclass of Form, they might as well just just subclass Button and use that across the app, as I suggested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52430355/5697).